# Touch gestures in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, midori

I just got my official Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen running. I opened up `midori` in fullscreen/kiosk mode and was a bit dissapointed.
The browser (or raspbian in general) interprets touch movement (swipe) as mouse selections. But i would like it to be more intuitive like a smartphone/tablet.
Is there a workaround?

EDIT: Raspberry is running Raspbian Wheezy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for touch gestures seems to be limited. What I found:

- There exists a FireFox (Iceweasel) extension [Grab and Drag](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag) that adds expected behavior (i.e. scrolling) to FireFox.
- Chromium supports touch gestures out of the box.
- There is [xstroke](https://cworth.org/~cworth/papers/xstroke/) that allows detection of hand writing to use this as input method. However, this tools seems to be unmaintained since 2003 and there is no package available in Raspbian.
- There is [Touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg), a Linux multitouch gesture recognizer. Unfortunately, there is also no pre-compiled package available for Raspbian.